# Most elegant way of deploying Maven build jars on unix box

Tags: deployment, maven

What is the most elegant way of deploying Maven build jars (through teamcity) on unix box.

Currently,we're deploying these jars only to artifactory.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean by "deploying" via RPM's or what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven-RPM-Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/)  to create the RPM's directly via Maven. In [this project](https://github.com/khmarbaise/CIEnv) you can see some examples how to use the Maven RPM Plugin.